# Add/remove items from Copy/Paste popover in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

When we highlight a text in UIWebView usually the copy, paste, define.. etc appears. How can I intercept this so that when I choose copy I call some other method/do something else. Is this possible?

When text is highlighted in a webview, a popover copy/paste/etc... shows up. Is there any way to customize this popover with other buttons or use my own custom view instead? I want to add options for changing text color, highlighting, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a custom button/action to the `[UIMenuController sharedMenuController]`:

```
UIMenuItem * highlight = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Highlight" action:@selector(didTapCreateHighlight:)];
[menuItems addObject:highlight];
[UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuItems = menuItems;
```

You can choose which items are active (appear in the `UIMenuController`) like this (this will display only the highlight button)(written off the top of my head, might contain some typos):

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"action: %@", NSStringFromSelector(action));

    if (action == @selector(didTapCreateHighlight:)) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's possible or how to ovverride the system methods. It might be as simple as overriding methods like `copy:`. Check the docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIMenuController/update). Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this within the context of my app only, or is it possible to register these as system events that are available at all times?

Comment: this doesn't hide Cut/Copy/Paste buttons in WebView